# How many contiguous subsets of size $N$ does an infinite grid have?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

Suppose I have an infinite grid. How many sets of grid points are there that contain $N$ contiguous grid points, and include the grid point at the origin?

So for example, if $N$ = 2, then there are 4 possibilities on a square grid:

```
0#0  000  000  000
0#0  0##  ##0  0#0
000  000  000  0#0
```

(Here I have not counted diagonal neighbors as being contiguous.) Is there a name for this quantity? Are there known formulas or tabulated values?

Comment: So this is in $\mathbb R^3 $? And by $(x_0,y_0,z_0) , (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ contiguous, do you mean that Min{(x_0-x_1, y_0-y_1, z_0-z_1) }=1?

Comment: In my case, I'm interested in a two dimensional square lattice. But certainly the question can be generalized to any type of lattice in any number of dimensions. In the case of a square grid, by contiguous I mean that $\left|x_0-x_1\right|+\left|y_0-y_1\right|=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an $n$, the number you want is $$nP(n)$$ where $P(n)$ is the number of fixed polyominoes of size $n$. A fixed [polyomino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) in your terminology is just a set of contiguous grid points without the specification that it must include the origin. The origin specification means we want to multiply the number of fixed polyominoes by $n$, because each of the $n$ points on a fixed polyomino could be the base point.

You can find a list of the number of fixed polyominoes here: [OEIS A001168](http://oeis.org/A001168).

Comment: Link is no longer working

Comment: @CodeWhisperer Thanks for letting me know. It is updated now.

Comment: It is greater than that because you can orient the polyomino in various ways.  Taking an I pentomino there are five positions horizontally and five positions vertically.  For some pentominos there are as many as $40$ positions because we have four orientations, two reflections, and five squares that could be the origin.

Comment: @RossMillikan Unless I am mistaken, the "fixed" part of "fixed polyomino" takes care of that. For example there are 2 fixed polyominoes of size 2, and 6 fixed polyominoes of size 3.

Comment: @RossMillikan So when $n=5$, the number Max wants is $5P(5)=5\times63=315$